# issues with installing fabric samples

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, smartcontracts, binaries, evm

some files are missing from the Fabric samples, docker images, and binaries download like the first-network folder and others. how do I get the missing files imported on vscode?

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing, **first-network** no longer exists as a Hyperledger Fabric sample. If you are using an old versions of Fabric (for example, v1.4) and the corresponding documentation, which does describe **first-network**, you will need to make sure you specify the appropriate version when installing Fabric components so it pulls the samples from the correct branch of the samples repository. For Fabric v1.4, that would be this branch:

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release-1.4

If you are using the [latest version of the Fabric and its documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html), **test-network** is now used to deploy a sample network and chaincode.